# setstate after splice with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object

I did a delete that works perfectly using react. Problem is after the delete I want to set the state to the new extraitMP3 to refresh and show automatically results after the Delete. This is the function of the delete :

```
 showDeleteConfirmation(value, id,idJson,thisHandler) {
    confirm({
      title: 'Voulez vous supprimer cette audio ?',
      content: '',
      okText: 'Oui, je confirme',
      okType: 'danger',
      cancelText: 'Non',
      onOk() {
        deleteMp3Request(id);

        var {extraitMP3} = thisHandler.state;
        Object.keys(extraitMP3).map(ids => {
          return(
          Object.keys(extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List).splice(idJson, 1)  
                )
        })
        thisHandler.setState({extraitMP3: extraitMP3})

        console.log('extraitMP3',extraitMP3)
        NotificationManager.success("le fichier audio est supprimé avec succès !", "");
      },
      onCancel() {
      },
    });
  }
```

this is the JSON i am mapping :

[image]

this is also my return

```
 return (
<div>
      {loader ? <CircularProgress className="gx-loader-400" /> : Object.keys(extraitMP3).map(ids => {
        return (
          <Card>

            <li key={ids}>
              <Card styleName="gx-card-list icon icon-data-display gx-mr-2 gx-text-blue gx-fs-xl">
                <div className="gx-media-body">
                  {extraitMP3[ids].Typenom}
                  &nbsp; 
                  {extraitMP3[ids].TypeIcon != null &&
                    displayIcon(extraitMP3[ids].TypeIcon)
                  } 
                </div>

                {Object.keys(extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List).map(idJson => {
                    return (
                      <div className="gx-main-content gx-mb-4">
                          <ContainerHeader match={this.props.match} />
                          <div className="gx-contact-item gx-dragndrop-item">

                            <DragHandle />

                            <div className="gx-col gx-job-title ">
                              {extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].intitule}
                            </div>

                            {extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].interpretation1Icon !== '' &&
                              <Tooltip title={extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].interpretation1Nom}>
                               {displayIcon(extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].interpretation1Icon)}
                              </Tooltip>
                            }

                            {extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].interpretation2Icon !== '' &&
                              <Tooltip title={extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].interpretation2Nom}>
                              {displayIcon(extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].interpretation2Icon)}
                              </Tooltip>
                            }

                            {extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].interpretation3Icon !== '' &&
                              <Tooltip title={extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].interpretation3Nom}>
                              {displayIcon(extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].interpretation3Icon)}
                              </Tooltip>
                            }

                            {extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].langueIcon !== '' &&
                              <div className="gx-col gx-job-title  gx-d-sm-flex gx-text-truncate gx-px-8">
                                <Tooltip title={extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].langueNom}>
                                  <i className={`flag flag-24 gx-mr-2 ${extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].langueIcon}`} />
                                </Tooltip>
                              </div>
                            }

                            <div className="gx-col gx-job-title  gx-d-sm-flex gx-text-truncate gx-px-8">
                              <Select
                                showSearch
                                style={{ width: '100%' }}
                                placeholder="Selection la choix de votre numÃ©ro de tÃ©lÃ©phone "
                                optionFilterProp="children"
                                onChange={handleChangeSelect}
                                defaultValue={selectOptions.get(extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].visibilite)}
                                filterOption={(input, Option) => Option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}
                              >
                                  {[...selectOptions].map(([value, label]) => <Option value={value}> {label} </Option>)}
                              </Select>
                            </div>

                            <div className="gx-col gx-job-title  gx-d-sm-flex gx-text-truncate gx-px-8">
                              <i className="icon icon-edit gx-fs-xl gx-text-gris" />
                            </div>

                            <div className="gx-col gx-job-title  gx-d-sm-flex gx-text-truncate gx-px-8">
                            <span className="gx-pointer">
                               <i  className="icon icon-trash gx-pointer gx-text-danger gx-fs-xxl"
                               id={extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].id}
                               onClick={e => this.showDeleteConfirmation(e.target.value, extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].id,idJson,this)} />
                            </span>                         
                             </div>

                          </div>

                      </div>
                    )
                })}
                  <NotificationContainer/>

                <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" labelCol={{ xs: 24, sm: 5 }} wrapperCol={{ xs: 24, sm: 12 }}>
                  Enregistrer
                </Button>
              </Card>
            </li>
          </Card>
        )
      }) }</div>
    )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `idJson`? What is `extraitMP3`? What is `extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List`?

Comment: The problem is that the array you're modifying isn't retained anywhere, it's the array created by `Object.keys(extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List)`, which is temporary unless you save it somewhere. I'm afraid it's not at all clear from the question above what change to your state you're trying to make (even after you posted the "JSON"), so I can't post an answer showing you how to make it.

Comment: yes exactly what I want to do is to retain the modified array. how to save it to put it on the setstate right after to refresh the new results

Comment: please check the return function whiich will clarify things for you I am doing a delete with the id. What I want to do is simply refreshing the page when deleting to show the results after the delete.

Comment: I answered the question more than 15 minutes ago. If you have any questions about the answer, please comment on the answer (after giving it a good thorough read). :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the array you're modifying isn't retained anywhere, it's the array created by `Object.keys(extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List)`, which is temporary unless you save it somewhere.

If the goal is to remove the property with the name in `idJson` from `extraitMP3[ids]`, then:

```
showDeleteConfirmation(value, id,idJson,thisHandler) {
  confirm({
    title: 'Voulez vous supprimer cette audio ?',
    content: '',
    okText: 'Oui, je confirme',
    okType: 'danger',
    cancelText: 'Non',
    onOk() {
      deleteMp3Request(id);
      // *** Changes start here ***
      thisHandler.setState(
          // Update callback
          ({extraitMP3: oldExtraitMP3}) => {
              // Clone the object we're changing
              const extraitMP3 = {...oldExtraitMP3};
              // Clone the subobject we're changing and remember it
              const entry = extraitMP3[ids] = {...extraitMP3[ids]};
              // Remove that property from the cloned subobject
              delete entry[isJson];
              // Return the new object with the changes
              return {extraitMP3};
          },
          // State change completion callback
          () => {
              // (Or if you don't want to wait for the state change to complete, you could
              // just put this after the setState call, not in a completion callback
              NotificationManager.success("le fichier audio est supprimé avec succès !", "");
          }
      );
      // *** Changes end here ***
    },
    onCancel() {
    },
  });
}
```

Note that it's important that you make the state changes in the `setState` **callback**, you can't make the changes and then call `setState` with the result, because **any** time you're updating state based on current state, you need to use the callback form, since [state updates are asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) and may be batched. (Otherwise, you risk using stale state to do the update.)

Comment: ok i read this. Smart to put everythoing under the setState but problem is I am doing some mapping above. I am getting simply ids and idJson undefined using your answer

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score -1):

You can use callBack to `setState`.

```
thisHandler.setState({extraitMP3: extraitMP3}, () => {
    console.log('extraitMP3',extraitMP3)
    NotificationManager.success("le fichier audio est supprimé avec succès !", "");
})
```